# Avoid Creating SimpleJdbcCall multiple times

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have to call callDb  around 20,000 in Service layer . with the below was it is taking 30 minutes because i am creating
SimpleJdbcCall  object everytime..How can i avoid creating SimpleJdbcCall object   for each call.

```
@Repository
public class JdbcActorDao  {



 void callDb ( ) 
 
 
 {
 
 
        SimpleJdbcCall simpleJdbcCall =
                new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate)
                        .withProcedureName("read_actor")
                        .withoutProcedureColumnMetaDataAccess()
                        .useInParameterNames("in_id")
                        .declareParameters(
                                new SqlParameter("in_id", Types.NUMERIC),
                                new SqlOutParameter("out_first_name", Types.VARCHAR),
                                new SqlOutParameter("out_last_name", Types.VARCHAR),
                                new SqlOutParameter("out_birth_date", Types.DATE)
                        );
    }




simpleJdbcCall.execute(...) ;


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the simpleJdbcCall as a field on the class and add a @PostConstruct method to initialize the SimpleJdbcCall in.

Like this

```
private SimpleJdbcCall simpleJdbcCall;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
     simpleJdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate)
                        .withProcedureName("read_actor")
                        .withoutProcedureColumnMetaDataAccess()
                        .useInParameterNames("in_id")
                        .declareParameters(
                                new SqlParameter("in_id", Types.NUMERIC),
                                new SqlOutParameter("out_first_name", Types.VARCHAR),
                                new SqlOutParameter("out_last_name", Types.VARCHAR),
                                new SqlOutParameter("out_birth_date", Types.DATE)
    );
}

public void performCall() {
    simpleJdbcCall.execute(...) ;
}
```

Comment: great .Will mark your answer as correct.Once i test it